# What should I expect from Italy Agriturismo accomodation?

Tags: italy

We're planning a small 2 weeks vacation in Italy (1 week in Rome, already booked). 
We want to get away from city centers, and look at smaller town and villages to chill out, drive around. We could book a rental in a village somewhere, but there are also Agriturismo accommodations.

As far as I understand, most Agriturismo accommodations are family owned Bed and Breakfast in small farms. Some provide breakfast and dinner, and some do not.

What else should I expect? What should I watch out for?

Comment: Always ask the agriturismo what their offering consists of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you are right. Agriturismo are usually family owned and located in the coutryside (agriturismo, literally can be transalted with "agricultural turism"); therefore you should expect something more personal than regular hotels (closer to airbnb).

Of course just like hotels, agriturismo have different range, so you can find small, rural ones and high-end ones. The price will vary a lot, depending on the quality of the accomodation.

Some may have a small farm attached (that you can visit) and they provide with local products (e.g. milk, yogurt, meat, fruits, ...)

Comment: Thanks, we decided to go in town (lucca) instead; we did not want to have to rent a car and drive.

Answer (score 3):

I did the same before. Going to Italy for two weeks and staying in Agriturismo accommodations only. It is indeed usually a family owned b&b in a farm. One of the benefits (depending on the offer of the accommodation) would be to join for dinner. If you like the Italian cuisine, then this is perfect way of enjoying it.